# Missing library for Android 6.x app when compiling with targetSdkVersion=23 (32-bit / 64-bit confusion)

Tags: android, 64-bit, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow

I compiling an Android application using Eclipse. The application has a library. I'm compiling against the Android 6.x SDK:

```
project.properties:: target=android-23
```

With the following manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Everything works fine and the application can run on both Android 5.x and 6.x.

If I upgrade the manifest to:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

The application fails on Android 6.x as it can't find the .so library of my application.

I have also:

```
Application.mk:: APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

I think that my application is confused about 32-bit/64-bit. How can I generate binaries with only a 32-bit library that will be loaded even if the target is API version 23 during compilation?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3028

Comment: It might be very well relevant. I did have the warning text relocation message with API 21. But since the upgrade I don't see any error when compiling, just the error when running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained here, the text relocation inside the library was the problem. Strangely, I was not getting any error during the compilation but it's not working if your target is API=23. Solution is either to remove all text relocations (which might be very difficult in my case) or to stay at API=22.

http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2015-December/055860.html

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=742633